# Как занести файлы в ListView

Tags: java, android, файлы

Пишу блокнот, не могу понять как занести список сохраненных файлов в `ListView`.

```
 File nameFiler = new File (namaFile);
        nameList.add(namaFile);
        //Исправить.
        OutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput(namaFile, 1);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
        osw.write(mEditText.getText().toString());
        osw.close();
```

Comment: Очень общий вопрос. Сохраненных куда?

Comment: Добавил правку.

Comment: Эта Ваша `правка` ясности не внесла.

Comment: Я попробовал вынести директорию через getAbsolutePath, но у меня пишут что файл находится в "/имя файла". Открытие происходит без указания расположения файла.

Comment: Рекомендую работать с БД, а не файлами.